# Chrome Devtools API: Programmatically mapping files to local workspace via SourcesPanel

Tags: google-chrome

I'm curious whether Chrome's [Devtools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-SourcesPanel) allows for programmatically mapping served files to local workspaces. I imagine that this would involve a) getting a list of served files and b) matching that up with similarly named files in the local workspace.

Accessing the SourcesPanel seems easy enough, but the functionality seems limited. Am I missing something?

[Screenshot for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sunc.png)